# Can you make a Podspec with conditional dependencies?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, podspec

I want to know if you can define dependencies on an static lib in a podspec depending on the type of the Target that the Pods project is going to be linked to. 
I need to be able to NOT add a dependency to an static lib if the target project is itself an static lib.

Why I need this?
[I've built a podspec for cocos2d-iphone v3](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/commit/82caef153616de366700a7c1ba36e213d7521fe5) and using it in a personal pet project. Works perfectly when you use it as a dependency for an executable. Unfortunately it doesn't works well the way I've organiced my project:
It's a multiplatform project app consisting in two xcode projects for the ios and osx executables. Both link to an static library with shared code (another xcode project). I've made the cocos2d a dependency for that last static library.
Unfortunately, cocos2d has a dependency  over lib z, which is also static. As you can't link two static libraries the link phase fails. The error message is as follows:

> file: -lz is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

It's easy to remove that dependency but I would prefer the process to be more easier for the end user.

My approach to solve this problem  would be add a conditional in the podspec so the lib z only is added if the project is not an static library. I guess it can be done with pre_install hooks, but they are discouraged by the cocoapods team.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I didn't understand "As you can't link two static libraries the link phase fails".  What do you mean?

Comment: Pods project file is compiled as an static library and depends on libz. My SharedCode library is also compiled as an static library, and when linking with the Pods library it fails because of that.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide a more precise error message but I'm currently at work.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've updated the answer with the error I get